C# ! (null-forgiving) not working as expected
I was looking over some code and suggested a fix for verifying something isn't null that can be null and suggested the following:
// Path: Employee.cs
public class Employee(string name, DateTime? arrivalTime = null) {
    public string Name = name;
    public DateTime? ArrivalTime = arrivalTime;
}

// Path: Program.cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
            "2024-12-10 10:30:00",
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        );

        var employees = new List<Employee>([
            new Employee("Matt"),
            new Employee("John", testDate),
            new Employee("Steve")
        ]);

        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            if (employee.ArrivalTime == null) continue;

            var arrivalDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(employee.ArrivalTime!);
            Console.WriteLine($"{employee.Name} arrives at {arrivalDate}.");
        }
    }
}

I assumed the null-forgiving operator would work. From my understanding, and reading the reference documentation it should suppresses the null value error. But I get the following error when compiling: "error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'".
I'm using the .NET 8.0.404 SDK.
However, changing the code to
var arrivalDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime((DateTime)employee.ArrivalTime);

or
var arrivalDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(employee.ArrivalTime ?? DateTime.Now);

makes it work fine.
Basically, my question is why does it not understand that a null suppression is safe in this context? My LSP understands that it's a nullable value if I remove the null check and warns me about it, but even with the null check it doesn't allow me to use the ! operator. Am I misunderstanding the operator usage?
Thanks in advance. :)

I would assume that you'd need to use employee.ArrivalTime!.Value.

@jmcilhinney You don't even need the ! in this case because nullability has already been checked. A simple employee.ArrivalTime.Value would work fine.

"Cannot convert from" is not an error about a null value.

You can use pattern matching which simplifies and combines test and usage: if (employee.ArrivalTime is DateTime arrival) { var arrivalDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(arrival); ... } or if (employee.ArrivalTime is { } arrival) { ... }


!(null-forgiving) not working as expected

It actually is

it should suppresses the null value error

No, it suppresses the warnings coming from the null-state analysis performed by compiler. For example the following:
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    var arrivalDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(employee.ArrivalTime.Value);
    Console.WriteLine($"{employee.Name} arrives at {arrivalDate}.");
}

Will produce the warning:

Warning CS8629 : Nullable value type may be null.

Which can be suppressed with the ! operator:
// will throw at runtime if ArrivalTime is null
var arrivalDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(employee.ArrivalTime!.Value);

This operator is used when you know that the value will never be null here but compiler can't prove it and is a way to tell the compiler "shut up, I'm smarter" (which is obviously not always the case and I personally have shot myself in the foot several times with !)
DateTime? is a nullable value type which is actually Nullable<DateTime> which does not have an implicit cast to DateTime, so you need to get DateTime which is usually done via the Value property of the Nullable<T> struct as was done in the preceding code.
Read more:

Nullable value types
Nullable reference types
Why does nullability check not work with value types?


Right. Thank you for clarification, I had assumed that it'd do type casting for some reason, seeing as the reference spoke of using it like that, but looking closer it was only for what looks to be the parent type of a field. Thanks again. :)

@BastianAsmussen was glad to help!
